# what can we do with libre office presentation

Tags: libreoffice

I cant get the point what can we do by using libre office presentation

is it as same as libre office writer. because when I operate I actually do not know what am i doing. can anyone help me for this

Comment: http://www.libreoffice.org/discover/impress/

Answer (score 2):

you can use it to prepare a presentation?

to ask a girl out,
to go for a job opening,
to sell something,
to ...

Usually, it is used to breakdown and logically summarize/organize the points you want to make and to show it on an overhead screen, large tv or projector. usually used as a support tool when presenting an idea, or item to a group of people.

the presentations prepared have a dimension suitable for a projector/tv/screen, with nice effects on the slides (though I don't use the effects much as it looks non-professional). you go through to the next slide with a click or keyboard arrows or space bar when in presentation mode (F5 I think).